# SQL Server Trigger On Update or Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

Here is my tables:

Report Table:

```
ReportID    Status
1           'out'
2           null
```

Log Table

```
LogID       Status      ReportID
1           'out'       1
```

When I insert a new record into Log table I want a trigger to update the corresponding status field.  Example:  Insert to log (LogID=2, Status='out', ReportID=2) I would want to update the report table for the matching ReportID(2) fild for Status so they match.

The output would end up like this;
Report Table:

```
ReportID    Status
1           'out'
2           'out'     //changed from null to out by the Log trigger
```

Log Table

```
LogID       Status      ReportID
1           'out'       1
2           'out'       2
```

The question here is how do I create a Trigger to update the second table when the first one either has a new insert, or an update to an existing record?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a view?

Comment: @lc. - What would a view do for OP here?  I'm genuinely curious, not making a smart aleck comment :)

Comment: @Tim I'm reading into the question a little bit and guessing the OP wants the Report table to show the latest Status as per the rows in the Log table. Therefore I am questioning the need to denormalize and store the same data in two different places.

Comment: @lc. - Ah, ok.  I see where you're going.  Thanks for answering - I was scratching my head there.  You should post that as an alternative way to resolve the OP's question, as others in the future might prefer it to a trigger, depending on requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
create trigger updatereport on log 
after insert, update
as
update r
set status = i.status
from report r 
  inner join inserted i on r.reportid = i.reportid;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c3c6/1)

Comment: In MS SQL Server Mgmt Studio should the trigger show up under Programmability>Database Triggers ... if so it didn't show up but I also received no errors when running the code you gave

Comment: @Kairan -- don't have it in front of me.  I'm pretty sure it shows up under the table -- expand the table and one of the folders you should see is triggers.  Here's a post I just looked up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346914/how-to-find-all-trigger-associated-with-a-table-with-sql-server

Comment: Thanks that is where it is found.