# SQL Server trigger and synchronization between 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

I have 2 databases, and when the data of `table_a` in `DB_1` changes, I want `table_b` in `DB_2` to change as well.

Columns in `table_a` and& `table_b` are different.

How to use a trigger to complete?

Comment: On **what** changes in `DB_1.table_A` do you want to do what **changes** to `DB_2.table_b` ?? You need to give us a lot more information! What operations should cause the trigger to fire? Once it's fired - what exactly should it do? What do your tables look like?

Comment: There are examples on the [`CREATE TRIGGER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189799.aspx) page. If you need more information, then as marc says, you need to provide far more information.

Comment: Thanks first ,the 2 tables have the same structure and info,but have different alias on each column.I want to ,when I insert new record into DB1.table_a ,want the trigger operate synchronized data to DB2.table_b.That's all ,maybe

Comment: How about the trigger I need Looks like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Trigger On Update or Insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138101/sql-server-trigger-on-update-or-insert)