# How to get a list of triggers with lists of all tables which are used inside the triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, oracle11g

How to get a list of triggers with lists of all tables which are used inside the triggers. Means both 
 
1) trigger created of table 

 2) tables used inside trigger logic ?

 Please provide the solution in oracle as well as in sql server?

Comment: Hope link below will help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346914/how-to-find-all-trigger-associated-with-a-table-with-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use `ALL_TRIGGERS` and `ALL_DEPENDENCIES` to find all triggers with their depending tables. This is: all tables that the DBMS sees dependant. So where dynamic SQL is used, the DBMS is blind to which tables the dynamic query will contain and you'll miss those.

```
select 
  t.owner || '.' || t.trigger_name as trigger_name, 
  t.table_owner || '.' || t.table_name as table_name,
  (
    select 
      listagg(d.referenced_owner || '.' || d.referenced_name, ', ') 
        within group (order by d.referenced_owner, d.referenced_name)
    from all_dependencies d 
    where d.owner = t.owner
    and d.name = t.trigger_name
    and d.type = 'TRIGGER'
    and d.referenced_type = 'TABLE'
    and not (d.referenced_owner = t.table_owner and d.referenced_name = t.table_name)
  )  as other_tables
from all_triggers t;
```

This is for Oracle (I don't know how the same is done in SQL Server. I guess it to be quite similar. SQL Server, too, will have system tables, you could get this information from).

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle try below query to get desired output

```
SELECT TRIGGER_NAME,TABLE_NAME,TRIGGER_TYPE, TRIGGERING_EVENT, LINE, TEXT 
FROM USER_TRIGGERS UT, USER_SOURCE US 
WHERE UT.TRIGGER_NAME=US.NAME;
```