# Can't find trigger even though it exists?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I was given a database and im trying to solve a trigger bug (it's pretty small change) however I've looked at every function/trigger so I did a:

```
select * from sys.triggers where name = 'NAME'
```

and it returned this:

```
NAME    1181247263  1   OBJECT_OR_COLUMN    2053582354  TR  SQL_TRIGGER 2012-11-13 09:41:13.707 2013-03-19 14:08:22.583 0   0   0   0
```

What exactly does this mean? is there literally a folder/function called OBJECT_OR_COLUMN

because I can't see it? Im doing this in SQL Server management studio btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will tell you the associated table...

```
select  t.name As TriggerName, 
        ss.name As SchemaName, 
        so2.name As TableName
from    sys.triggers t
Join    sysobjects so
        On  t.object_id = so.id
Join    sysobjects so2
        On  so.parent_obj = so2.id
Join    sys.schemas ss
        On  so2.uid = ss.schema_id
Where   t.name = 'NAME'
```

Answer (score 0):

The first column is name, which appears to be the name of your trigger is 'NAME'

If you need to find where it is, use this query from here [Need to list all triggers in SQL Server database with table name and table's schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305691/need-to-list-all-triggers-in-sql-server-database-with-table-name-and-tables-sch)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to query sys.objects to see where the parent is.

This should find it for you:

```
select * from sys.objects where object_id = '2053582354'
```

The "OBJECT_OR_COLUMN" means the parent of the trigger is an object or column.