# Update generate two rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that have 1 row
table 1

```
____________________________________________
id_employee | month| year| score| nbr_month|
____________________________________________
14          |  2   |2015 | 15   | 4        |
____________________________________________
```

and i Want update this row
so I created i stored procedure

```
update table 1
set score=10,nbr_month=4
where id_employee=14 and month=2 and year=2015
```

but the result of the excution of Stored Procedure generate another row

```
____________________________________________
id_employee | month| year| score| nbr_month|
____________________________________________
14          |  2   |2015 | 15   | 4        |
14          |  2   |2015 | 10   | 4        |
____________________________________________
```

So please where is the problem?
Thank you in advance.

Stored procedure is:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[update_score] 
 @id_employee int, 
 @score int, 
 @nbr_month int, 
 @month int, 
 @year int 
as 
begin 
  update table1 
   set score = @score
      ,nbr_month = @nbr_month 
   where id_employee = id_employee 
     and [month] = @month 
     and [year]  = @year 
end
```

Comment: No, an `update` does never create a new record. An `insert` does.

Comment: Check the stored procedure or if there's a trigger on the table.

Comment: Can you show the stored procedure definition?

Comment: @DavidG how can I determine if a trigger existe or not when I execute my stored procedure?

Comment: @M.Ali 
`code`/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[update_score]    Script Date: 05/24/2015 13:30:30 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[update_score]
@id_employee int,
@score int,
@nbr_month int,
@month int,
@year int
as 
begin
update table 1
set score=@score,nbr_month=@nbr_month 
where id_employee=id_employee  and  month=@month and year=@year
end `code`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305691/need-to-list-all-triggers-in-sql-server-database-with-table-name-and-tables-sch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. Update modifies already existing records. So your code might be running an `insert` command. Or calling a stored procedure which does the same. Or a `trigger` is triggered. But certainly, the `update` will not generate new records.

Answer (score 0):

There might be update Trigger written on table.thats the only way otherwise it couldn't.