# INSERT query adds row in database but removes last row

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I have hit a speed bump in debugging a system I didn't write. Every time an INSERT query is committed, after using sorting the table, the last row is always deleted (i.e. inserting C on a table of A B D E F, results to A B C D E). If the INSERT is done on the last row (i.e. inserting G on a table of A B C D E F, results to A B C D E G), it replaces the last row.

Any idea where I should try looking into? Debugging on Eclipse.

Comment: can you post your code.

Comment: Any triggers on the table?

Comment: the thing is that the code is already too large and I find it impossible to see where the problem is to post which code I need to show. I believe there are no triggers too.

Comment: @user7843556 No need to guess: you can check this on the database itself. [How to list SQL server triggers on table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305691/need-to-list-all-triggers-in-sql-server-database-with-table-name-and-tables-sch)

Comment: Used to the top answer and no results/triggers where found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to answer without codes. All I see is the behavior.

What are you trying to know? How to debug?

Just find all parts communicates with the database. Then look at its sql statement.

Also sql statements usually returns a value.. example an update will return how many affected rows, insert returns the new id. You can look at these values for clues. You should also make use of breakpoints in debugging mode.

Comment: It's fine. I already figured out that the system is giving me a bad sql query. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert Into TableA ('CC') Values ('X');

Declare @XX char(5);

Select Top 1 @XX = CC From TableA order by CC desc;

Delete from TableA Where CC = @XX;
```