# Can I select update triggers?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Instead of something like

```
SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE CONTAINS(Name, 'Update');
```

I would like to do something like

```
SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE ("TRIGGER IS FOR UPDATE")
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to list all triggers in SQL Server database with table name and table's schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305691/need-to-list-all-triggers-in-sql-server-database-with-table-name-and-tables-sch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'ExecIsUpdateTrigger') = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into SysObjects and SysComments, below query should work:

```
select * from 
sysobjects, syscomments
WHERE sysobjects.id = syscomments.id and type='tr'
and text like '%AFTER UPDATE%'
```

Comment: But if I have only `FOR UPDATE`?