# Trying to drop a table that was previously used for a Database Trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I created a database trigger last week in our QA environment to track schema and database changes. I am trying to remove the tables, and I have removed all the triggers but when I try to drop the last table  I get the following error

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trg_Database_changes, Line 8 [Batch Start Line 2]
> Invalid object name 'Audit_logs'

This makes me think I still have a trigger out there but I can't find it. I have looked in every database.

Any ideas?

```
USE [master]
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
           WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Audit_logs]') AND type in (N'U'))
    DROP TABLE master.[dbo].[Audit_logs]
GO
```

Comment: Hi, have you try to list all triggers ? i think this query can help you https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-triggers/sql-server-list-all-triggers/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305691/need-to-list-all-triggers-in-sql-server-database-with-table-name-and-tables-sch

Comment: I have.  That's how I checked to see if it existed somewhere I didn't know.

Comment: for sure you have a trigger on your database that tracks database changes & probably it is using the same table "Audit_logs" , that's why its failing

Comment: I think you have procedure (stored procedure) and this SP use Audit_Logs table

Comment: So you have no triggers in `sys.triggers` in each user database, nor any triggers in `sys.server_triggers` (where `all server` triggers are listed)?

Comment: DDL triggers cannot be seen in sys.objects. Try sys.triggers - which has both DML and DDL triggers.

Comment: I found the issue.  It was a server level trigger.  Thank you all for your help.  Those don't show up in sys.triggers either.